# does easymock depend on net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer?

Tags: easymock

I  am trying to  complete  a  tutorial about  easymock to use  it  for  the  first  time.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EasyMock/article.html

I am using 
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (  Build id: 20100218-1602)
- Junit 4   plugin
- easymock 3.0

After  creating a project  as  described  below  and  executing as  a  JUNIT testI  get  the  error.

```
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer**
```

What  is this error  and  how  can I  fix it? It  occurs  on the  line

```
EasyMock.replay(calcMethod);
```

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer     at
>   org.easymock.internal.ClassExtensionHelper.getControl(ClassExtensionHelper.java:57)
>   at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControl(EasyMock.java:2068)     at
>   org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(EasyMock.java:1970)     at
>   income.IncomeCalculatorTest.testCalc1(IncomeCalculatorTest.java:33)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     ... 28 more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah, i think you need it.

http://cglib.sourceforge.net/

its aslo probably in some sort of dependencies directory in the easymock download

Answer (score 1):

From EasyMock 3.0 page:
To perform class mocking, also add [Objenesis](http://objenesis.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html) and [Cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) to your classpath.